# How to symbolicate the log of an iOS app that contains my framework?

Tags: ios, frameworks, swift

My framework is integrated inside third party iOS app and they complain that their app crashes sometimes because of my framework. Of course, I want to investigate this issue, but the crash that they send is just partly symbolicated. For example, it looks something like that:

```
#0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  MyFramework                    0x10763cfe9 __swift_memcpy16_4 + 9352
1  MyFramework                    0x10763d89c __swift_destroy_boxed_opaque_existential_0 + 306
2  MyFramework                    0x107694108 globalinit_33_C8CD7BA31FDCD9392B0CECAD743A02CC_func98 + 17641
3  MyFramework                    0x10763cfb0 __swift_memcpy16_4 + 8375
```

I know that in order to symbolicate it I need .app, .dSYM and .crash files. But as long as this app is not mine I don't have .app file. Is there any way to symbolicate this part of the crash log that is relevant to my framework only?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm encountering a similar problem.

Comment: Yes and no. The only way to do that is to send your dSYM file to the client.